# sbt: Module not found: sbt-buildinfo

Tags: scala, sbt

I have created a hello-world sbt project and I would like to fetch a GitHub dependency. In particular, that dependency is the Scala compiler. In particular, I am creating a directory `scala-dep-example` and inside that directory, I have the following two files:

```scala
// File 1: Test.scala
object ScalaDepTest extends App {
    println("Hello from Scala dep !")
}
```

```scala
// File 2: build.sbt
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "me",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  )),
  name := "a name"
).dependsOn(ScalaDep)

lazy val ScalaDep = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/scala/scala.git"))
```

Inside that directory, I run the `sbt` command (which initializes the sbt version to `1.1.1` in `scala-dep-example/project/build.properties`) and I am getting the following output:

```
[info] Updated file /work-path/scala-dep-example/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.1.1
[info] Loading project definition from /work-path/scala-dep-example/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/work-path/scala-dep-example/project/"), "scala-dep-example-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /work-path/.sbt/1.0/staging/d8828f83c86b476a38b1/scala/project/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/work-path/.sbt/1.0/staging/d8828f83c86b476a38b1/scala/project/project/"), "scala-build-build")...
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.6.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /work-path/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo_2.12_1.0/0.6.1/sbt-buildinfo-0.6.1.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /work-path/.sbt/preloaded/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/0.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////work-path/.sbt/preloaded/com/eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo_2.12_1.0/0.6.1/sbt-buildinfo-0.6.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.6.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-buildinfo:0.6.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-buildinfo:0.6.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/work-path/.sbt/1.0/staging/d8828f83c86b476a38b1/scala/project/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:scala-build-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.6.1: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2383)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.6.1: not found
```

How can I fix this in general? I found some slightly similar issues online but none was quite the same so I decided to post this.

I would really appreciate any hints/feedback on that.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.6.1")` to `project/plugins.sbt` and otherwise [follow the instructions on the sbt-buildinfo plugin page](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo)?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin . That was very helpful ! Even though this specific line didn't work, all I had to change was the `sbt-buildinfo` version to `0.7.0` and also change my sbt version to `0.13.17` which is the sbt used by the scala repo. Both of these changes were necessary. I then got another issue but I will submit another question for that. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sbt plug-in that you want to use is published for sbt 0.13.

Solution: Change the file `scala-dep-example/project/build.properties` to the following content:

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

Comment: How can I find out for wich sbt version which version of the plugin is published?

Comment: Google sbt-buildinfo, click the first result, then you will see the version information in its README